# Searching for attractions, hotspots, beaches on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-places-api

I am using the Google Maps v3 api with Google Places to look for interesting places nearby.

When I search for "beach" keyword (praia in my language) it returns hostels, restaurants, etc with that word in the name

Is there a way to look for tourists spots on Google Maps? i mean the interesting things to do in each city, like the Copacabana Beach, Eiffel tower, Big Ben etc

what should I do get this set of results according to one given point (current position)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `types=` parameter to filter by place type when searching, and/or to remove unwanted places from the responses.  The full list of types is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types).

For example, filtering the responses by `natural_feature` should leave only "real" beaches.  (Unfortunately this particular type is not supported for searching.)

Comment: are you sure? this is what is written in the reference: `Note: The types below are not supported in the types filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place.`

Comment: Oops, good catch, updating.  But you can still use that filter the returned results.